# Getting reputation back after deleting answer

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes, deleted-answers

Today it happened to me 2 times, I posted answer to questions and I got 3 (and 1 on another answer) downvotes on my answer. After that I deleted my answers. Then after some time when I check my reputation, it get back to initial before getting downvotes.

So whenever we delete our post with downvotes return that reputation?

Comment: It also restores the $-1$ point to each downvoter of your deleted answer when you delete it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. Votes cast earlier on deleted content do not influence your reputation down the road; roughly speaking, the reputation is determined based on non-deleted content only. (There are some exceptions to this, for example, reputation from well-received posts that are only deleted after a considerable period of time is preserved.)

Note though that deleted content still counts towards automatic posting bans. Thus, there is some cost in posting an answer and deleting it later when it got downvoted.