# Who can accept answers and what about downvotes on deleted content?

Tags: support, down-votes, accepted-answer

1. Can someone other than the OP accept an answer to the question? Can the OP find out who accepted the answer?
2. If the answer to 1, is yes, and the OP disagrees, does the OP have any recourse?
3. If I provide the only answer to a question and it is clearly correct, what do I do if my answer doesn't get accepted? How much time does the OP have to accept an answer?
4. If I provide the wrong answer to a problem, it gets down votes, I discover my error, and edit my answer explaining my error for the benefit of others, can I get my down votes deleted? If I delete my wrong answer, will the down votes be deleted?
5. If my question needs to be edited, someone else edits my question and then answers the edited question, I decide that the edit does not reflect my intended question, I reedit the question, the answer the prior editor provided is no longer relevant. What should I do with the answer? Suppose it has already been accepted by someone else.

Comment: All reputation changes (both positive and negative) are removed after a post is deleted: [Getting reputation back after deleting answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25503). There is an exception if the post has been on site for long enough time before the deletion: [Reputation tab seems to be insensitive to deletion of upvoted answers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24905). (When considering deletion of a post, you should keep in mind that both deleted posts and downvotes may influence [whether you get post ban](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/post-ban/info).)

Answer (score 4):

1. No.

Three. You ask the questioner whether there is anything else you can do.

4. No, but you can hope the downvoters notice the edit and rescind their downvotes. Yes, if you delete, the downvotes go away (I think).
5. Nothing.

Comment: Can the editor of a question, who is not the OP, accept an answer to the edited question?

Comment: re 4, once deleted the votes have no more effect on the point count of the user (except for "old" content, but that's tangential here), in this sense indeed the dv "go away". But the negative score is still visible and would come back into effect once undeleted.

Comment: @StephenMeskin no, this is a corollary of 1. Noone but the original poster of the question can accept an answer.

Comment: Also note that downvotes on deleted content contribute towards your potential [post-ban](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/answer-bans).

Answer (score 2):

Nobody except for the original asker of a question can accept an answer (except maybe diamond mods in certain circumstances, I'm not sure), and the answerer can retract that acceptance at any time. This can also be issued at any time, though if the poster of a question never accepts an answer, there's not much you can do other than to comment on the post and politely ask them to do so.

If an answer is written, and you edit the question so the answer is no longer valid, you can politely comment on the answer telling the poster why their answer no longer answers the question, and they might change it, or they might not. There's not much you can do other than that

If you delete a question or an answer, the voting, and also reputation from that voting, is removed from the site with the question, so if you received 4 down votes and delete the answer, you will receive your 8 reputation back as if the question never existed. (This does not apply to the -100 reputation penalized for posting spam questions)

Comment: Diamond mods can't accept answers to anybody else's questions, only the asker can. Well, technically, somebody with database access could, I guess.